# How to add conditionally an element in an array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to add an element to an array in mongoDB, but only id it doesn't already exist. For now I do as follows:

```
await db
    .collection(config.MY_COLLECTION)
    .updateOne(
      { _id: ObjectId(userId) },
      { $push: { my_array: ObjectId(idToAdd) } }
    );
```

In this way I can add the same element x times. How can I avoid it without querying the DB before and do it conditionally server side. I want to do it directly DB side.

Comment: Have you checked out [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)?

Comment: Very good @ray! That's the one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace $push with $addToSet